# Can anyone know how to post a photo as a comment on facebook using android?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Face book recently gave the facility to do comments as photos . I'm currently developing a android application to do this photo-commenting . can anyone give a good solution for it?

Comment: Where are you having troubles? Can you post your code you already did?

Comment: I want a sample android coding to do photo commenting using facebooksdk . Can u help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/), you can add an attachment in the form of an image url see :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/comment

Send a request and add [additionnal parameter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests/#step3) (in this case an image src)

You might want to publish a photo first, if so have a look at : 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#publish

Comment: Thanks for your reply . i setup the facebookSDk and all . and i read those links that you given .  Can you provide a simple sample android coding to post a photo comment . then it would be a good guide for me and i can easily understand the workflow in this process nah!.